# Проверка введённых данных в поле с помощью jQuery (символы, кириллица или латиница)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Проверка введённых пользователем данных в **input**. Хочу попробовать сделать проверку формы на jQuery без плагинов, а именно нужно проверить введённые пользователем данные на предмет присутствия в них тех или иных символов (пробел, %&#@ и тд). Любой из этих символов не должен присутствовать в поле. Также было бы неплохо сделать проверку (кириллица или латиница)?

Какие варианты это сделать? Или стоит лучше будет использовать плагины?

**ИЗМЕНЕНО:**

Сделал такую проверку данных на ходу:

```
$('#userNameID').on('input', function(){
    let uName1_testA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g.test(uName1);
    if(uName1_testA === true) {
        $('#uNameMessageID').text("error")
    }else if (uName1_testA === false) {
        $('#uNameMessageID').text('');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="mainForm">
        <div>
            <span>Your name</span><br>
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Enter your name" autocomplete="off" id="userNameID">
            <span id="uNameMessageID"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Send your data</button>
    </form>
```

**ПРОБЛЕМА:**
Столкнулся с проблемой когда в поле вводишь одни пробелы тогда скрипт не выдаёт результат, но если выводить ошибки в консоль (console.log()) тогда все работает прекрассно. Также этот обработчик события не реагирует на то когда я удаляю данные из поля, только после их замены происходит проверка. Как решить, нужно сменить обработчик события?

Comment: В функции которую вы здесь вставили не определяется uName1. Если определить её как this.value, то я не наблюдаю перечисленных проблем: https://codepen.io/Lightgazer/pen/eYpBjWp 
Возможно дело в версии jquery

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать обработчик события input, проверять содержимое поля регулярными выражениями:

```
$('input').on('input', function () {
    const str = this.value
  if ((/^([а-яА-ЯёЁ]*)$/.test(str))) console.log('В поле только кириллица')
  if ((/^([a-zA-Z]*)$/.test(str))) console.log('В поле только латиница')
  if ((/^([\s%&#@])*$/).test(str)) console.log('В поле недопустимые символы')
  //если нужно запретить ввод определёных символов
  this.value= str.replace(/[\s%&#@]/g, '')
})
```